# How to release the Bitmap of D2D1 correctly when closing the Form?

Tags: c#, directx, direct2d, sharpdx, direct3d11

I'm using SharpDX to draw a list of Bitmaps. I made a Main menu form to select which bitmaps are being drawn. After that, it will open a new form to create DX device, factory, swapchain and so on. Then the bitmaps will be drawn on the new form. All the bitmaps are saved in a LinkedList. Then I can use my Unload() to Unload it and remove it from the list.

```cs
    public void Unload() {
        lock (this) {
            locked = true;
            lock (loadedList) {  // loadedList is the LinkedList contains all the bitmaps (100 bitmaps).
                loadedList.Remove(this);
            }
            if (Bitmap != null) {
                Bitmap.Dispose();
                Bitmap = null;
            }
        }
        locked = false;
    }

    public static void UnloadAll() {
        lock(loadedList) {
            while (loadedList.Count > 0) {
                loadedList.Last.Value.Unload();
            }
        }
    }
```

When I'm about to exit, I Unload all the bitmap and close the DX form **immediately**. However, the memory is not released. Now only my Main menu form are running but there a still a lot of memory **NOT** being released. Here is the memory chart: [Close DX Form immediately](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JT1ld.png)

Then I tried again. When I'm about to exit, I just Unload all the bitmaps but not close the DX form. I keep it running Render loop and just BeginDraw() and EndDraw(). But this time, I find the memory is released, but not **immediately**. Like this: [Memory chart from VS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FBRnK.png)
As you can see, after I unload all the bitmaps, the memory just drop but **NOT** to it's lowest. After 3 seconds it start to drop again and recover to the normal level, this drop is automatically. If I close the Form **immediately**, this will not happen.
So I'm wondering how the release it **immediately**. If I can't, how can I wait for the second release and then close the DX form?
By the way, some big 3D games will stuck for a period of time when exiting, is it waiting for the second release?

I've shot 4 snapshots when running: [4 snapshots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vUuLb.png)
1st is when all the bitmaps are loaded.
2nd is when I Unload all the bitmaps, now the memory has not been released: [Compare with 1st snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wGkfI.png)
3rd is when the memory first drop: [Compare with 2nd snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LtWFR.png)
4th is when the memory second drop: [Compare with 3rd snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PHmnn.png)

Comment: You have no memory profile data here to prove much at all. Where are the stats on these objects in memory and what generation of collection it is? Secondly you are trying to diagnose memory issues with a graph, there may not be issues at all, there maybe, but how can we (or more importantly you) possibly know without the correct information? I suggest you get familiar with how to use and read a memory profiler and identify memory issues

Comment: @TheGeneral All the bitmaps are created and added into the LinkedList named loadedList, and there are 100 1920x1080 bitmaps in total. Each of them takes up about 10MB memory, so about 1GB in total. I have think about it for a long time and debug it again and again, the result is if I close the DX form immediately after I dispose all the bitmaps (essentially COM Objects), it will not be dispose thorough. It can be dispose completely only when I dont close the DX form and wait for a while.

Comment: My point is, its hard to really know whats going on. All we can do is make guesses. To really work out whats going on in both these situations, you will need an actual detailed memory profile, that way you (us) can work out what generation your objects are in (in the collection process) Whether they should be there, and whether you can do something more about it.

Comment: @TheGeneral How can I generate a memory profile? I'm not very good at it... I tried to use Performance profiler, however, I can't get something useful...It can't catch bitmaps being used

Comment: have a look at this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/profiling/memory-usage?view=vs-2019

Comment: @TheGeneral Thank you a lot and I have add some screenshots into my question. I just noticed that Bitmap is not directly managed by GC, its a COM object. Here are some details: http://sharpdx.org/wiki/usage/

Comment: difficult to say w/o a reproducing project. Devil hides in details.